# Windows XP или Windows 7 для веб и в общем программирования?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp

**Дайте совет**

У меня есть компьютер с операционной системой `Windows XP`. Одна проблема, на ней хром <s>15 год</s> 2015 года, я думаю это не очень тестить сайты на старом хроме. Я решил выйти в интернет с этим вопросом (зашел на *stackoverflow*).Мне пришлось жить с этим вопросом 2 минуты, подумал не поставить ли **Windows 7**. В игры играть я конечно же не буду, мне нужно понять, переходить мне, или нет. Да и написано **Designed for Windows 7**
И да какую версию *Windows 7* поставить (*Starter*(точно не ее), *home basic*(и это не желательно), *home premium, professional, ultimate*)

***Характеристики:***

---

- *Процессор:*   Intel atom N450 (2 ядра, 1.66 гигагерц);
- *Видео:*  Intel graphics media accelerator 3150 (256мб видео)
- *Оперативная Память:* 2 гигабайта
- *Жесткий Диск:* 256gb hdd

---

Вопрос, **остаться на windows xp или перейти на windows 7?**

Comment: Продай его и купи современный компьютер. Всё равно, рано или поздно, придется, ибо под новые технологии и нужды придется ставить всяко разно, что такого компа не хватит в любом случае, особенно памяти... особенно если она (что скорее всего)  DDR1 - DDR2 ..... win7 и некоторые программки для разработки потянет, но со скрипом в сердце

Comment: А на каких языках планируешь писать? И вообще для чего тебе это всё?

Comment: Ламп на него, в сеть со статическим ир, под стол поставить, и будет ему вторая жизнь.

Comment: hta, js, php 7, assembler.

Comment: @0xdb lamp? то есть предлагаете линукс ставить? он еще более требовательнее к памяти, чем винда, разве нет? будет биться в конвульсиях)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Почему,  скорее наоборот. Линксовое ядро, как известно,  очень щядящее к памяти и ресурсам.

Comment: @0xdb ядро — может быть. Программы — нет. Некоторые одинаковые программы на linux и win, почему-то на линуксе  потребляют от 10% памяти больше, чем на винде.  А если учесть то, что человеку нужно будет ориентироваться на некоторые специфические вещи, такие как браузер и в частности IE и EDGE, то это еще доп нагрузка в виде PlayOnLinux или Wine и прочие дополнения.

Comment: Так давайте, решите,  могу поставить и linux но многие пользуются EDGE  и совсем долбанутые юзают IE.

Comment: @Duoxx мое мнение было озвучено еще в первом комментарии)) Объем HDD позволит работать с тем, что вы хотите, а вот все остальные параметры, не зависимо от ОС — сомнительно. Имхо: однозначно новый комп. А дальше уже какая ОС будет не особо важно.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, веб-стек на винде жрёт меньше ресурсов, чем на linux? Ого, что-то новенькое.

Comment: @donRumata что ты подразумеваешь под словами "веб-стек"?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, саму ос, веб-сервер, бд и какой-нибудь язык программирования типа php или python.

Comment: Поддержу совет поставить Linux. Для старого железа поддержка более-менее вылизана, и среда исполнения будет очень похожа на то, что на серверах обычно встречается. Нехватку ОЗУ, а она с современными браузерами будет, скомпенсируете подкачкой. А вопрос надо закрывать, ибо холиварня.

Comment: @donRumata а разрабатывать, писать код, отлаживать, тестировать, собирать проект, автоматизировать некие процессы, возможная правка в графических файлах, шаблонах верстки - это, конечно же, всё люди делают в уме, не прибегая к помощи компьютера и каких-либо программ

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ты перепрыгнул на другую тему. Начиналось вроде бы за то, кто жрёт меньше ресурсов. Теперь про функциональность речь. Ну если думаешь, что на linux всё вышеперечилсенное сделать нельзя (bash, docker, lamp, vbox, vagrant), то я тебя видимо разочарую.

Comment: @donRumata  я сразу написал про программы. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663137/windows-xp-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-windows-7-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#comment957629_663137 -в этом основная проблема. То, что ты не читаешь, прежде чем писать-не моя проблема ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯   ..`Ну если думаешь, что на linux всё вышеперечилсенное сделать нельзя` - память! ПАМЯТЬ, чувак!! и производительность. Причем тут нельзя что-то сделать? Читай выше и не тупи

Comment: уже не важно, купил mac.

Answer (score 0):

Для веб-программирования только "7". 2 гигабайта - норма. Голой (без сервиспаков) ХП хватает 256 метров. С СП3 - 512. 7-32 - 1 гига хватает. Так что с ОЗУ - норма. Гуглехром под ХП не обновляется, да и Палемуна лучше под 7 ставить. У атома нет под него инструкций, но всё равно должен шевелиться. А Палемун сейчас наиболее популярный браузер для тех у кого процессоры не слишком стары и кто не под ХП сидит. Однозначно надо на 7 переходить!

Comment: Немного припоздали)